# Is seam-gen still compatible with glassfish 3.1.2?

Tags: glassfish-3, seam2

Currently I'm trying to deploy a web app in ear format in glassfish app server.

Following the instructions from jboss on how to use seam-gen, I was able to create the project. But when I invoked gf-deploy, I got the ff error:

```
gf-deploy-datasource:
     [exec] Authentication failed for user: null
     [exec] (Usually, this means invalid user name and/or password)
     [exec] Command add-resources failed.
     [exec] Authentication failed for user: null
     [exec] (Usually, this means invalid user name and/or password)
     [exec] Result: 1
```

Seems like glassfish 3.1.2 doesn't allow anonymous deployment anymore, if so how should I specify the credentials in the ant glassfish-build.xml?

Any suggestions?

Thanks,

czetsuya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, currently most glassfish version 3.1.2 commands requires 'user' and 'passwordFile' parameter. So you need to change how you invoke them, example add-resources:

```
asadmin add-resources --user admin --passwordFile /localfile
```